# How to change timezone of DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make an mobile app for a reservation system. Users can reserve the product from different timezones. So when a user from NY city tries to reserve a product from Paris, I need to be sure user selected the time in Europe/Paris timezone. Currently swiftUI datepicker uses the system current timezone which is of course GMT-5 so when they select 13:00 the Date() object sets itself to 18:00 UTC, but I need him/her to be select in GMT+1 so when they select 13:00 I should set the Date() object to 12:00 UTC. I have tried to use environment value for timezone but it changes the timezone application wide, I just need to change the timezone of datepicker not all application.
Here are the solutions I've tried to change timezone

```
DatePicker("", selection: $viewModel.tripRequest.date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .font(.custom("Gilroy-Regular", size: 36))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)!)
```

I've also tried to use introspect with no luck

```
DatePicker("", selection: $viewModel.tripRequest.date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .font(.custom("Gilroy-Regular", size: 36))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .introspectDatePicker { datePicker in
                        datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI's `DatePicker` uses the device's `Timezone` by default.

You can specify a `Timezone` using `.environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(identifier: "Specific identifier")!)`

But `Date` is in UTC so if the user picks a date in one timezone when viewed in another timezone it will be adjusted. You can't change the timezone for `Date`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorldTimeView: View {
    @State private var date: Date = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            DatePicker("US", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            //US Date Picker
                .environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!)
           
            
            DatePicker("Paris", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            //Paris Date Picker
                .environment(\.timeZone, TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET")!)
            
            //User/Device Date Picker
            DatePicker("Local", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
        }
    }
}

struct WorldTimeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WorldTimeView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But this is changing the timezone application wide isn’t it? I just need to change timezone of datepicker. If I change the timezone via environment variables all other views in the application with time data get affected

Comment: @Emre no just for the pickers. `environment` affects the views below it. As you can see the local picker is unaffected by the other 2.

Comment: Then, I have messed up somewhere independent from this issue, thank you

Comment: @Emre introspect can make changes that affect the entire app,I suggest you don’t use that framework. If you look at their documentation it says that it shouldn’t be used in production apps. Also a lot of the brute force UIKit modifiers afect the entire app.